# LaTeX mathematical symbols are shown incorrectly in Github Pages

Tags: markdown, github-pages, mathjax

I'm creating a web-site using markdown and I use VS Code and Github Pages for it. I want to include the LaTeX formula to the site. The code is:

```
There is a formula: $x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}$
```

The Open Preview renders it as expected:

Open Preview

[image: 1]

I've uploaded it to Github Pages and now it looks like this:

Github Pages

[image: 2]

Am I doing something wrong?

I had thoughts I had some syntax mistakes but when I was reading docs I found nothing wrong with my code. I tried to copy&paste but the problem was the same.

Comment: Markdown doesn't know anything about LaTeX. You'll need to use something like KaTeX or MathJax. Did you set that up, possibly as a plugin to whatever is generating your static site?

Comment: @Chris thank you so much, using MathJax really helped)